# How do i make an ExtrudeGeometry face an Object with the Object3D.lookAt() function?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I need to make a 3D Polygon that faces another Object. Is there any good way to do that? I thought of using ExtrudeGeometry but i don't know how to apply the Object3D.lookat() function to it. I would appreciate any help :)

This is the Code i have for now:

```
  var position = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

  var polyhedronPts = [];
    polyhedronPts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-100, 600));
    polyhedronPts.push(new THREE.Vector2(300, 600));
    polyhedronPts.push(new THREE.Vector2(600, -100));
    polyhedronPts.push(new THREE.Vector2(200, 100));
    polyhedronPts.push(new THREE.Vector2(400, 200));

    polyhedronShape = new THREE.Shape(polyhedronPts);
    var extrudeSettings = {
      amount: 5
    }; 
    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(polyhedronShape, extrudeSettings);

    geometry.lookAt(position); 

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;

    sceneEl.object3D.add(mesh);
```

The geometry.lookAt(sphereposition); line should make the object face [0,0,0]
but it doesn't. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You want to extrude the polygon towards a point or have an already extruded mesh rotated towards a point?

Comment: @ScieCode Id like to have an already extruded mesh rotated towards a point :)

Comment: If you could add a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/j4bsq573/) with your code, I will be able to review what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`.lookAt()` is a `Object3D` function, [reference](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt).

This means you need to use it on your mesh object, not your geometry.

To rotate an object towards a `targetObject`, you can use `object.lookAt( targetObject.position )`. This will detect the current position of the targetObject and rotate it accordingly.

I've set up an interactive [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvcr52fu/). You can drag the cube and the cone will automatically point towards it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it and it doesn't work for me. Basically i have added the line: `mesh.object3D.lookAt(position);` Are you sure it works with the `ExtrudeGeometry`? Do you think anything about my code might be wrong? Or could you show me an instance how it would work with the `ExtrudeGeometry`? That would be really helpfull, thanks alot for the help :)!

Comment: try `mesh.lookAt( position )`, without `.object3D`. Mesh is already an instance of `Object3D`

Comment: Idk doesn't work for me but maybe i'm doing something wrong, i have tried it with `ShapeGeometry` now but i got the same problem. Could you show me an example where it works with shapegeometry ? :)

Comment: It is the exact same logic @RezarakSL. the geometry doesn't interfere with this.